# couldn't resolve resource @drawable/loginbutton_selector

Tags: android

I got this error. Would somebody know how to fix it. All i had written

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- When item pressed this item will be triggered -->
    <item android:state_pressed="true"><shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="3dp" />

        <solid android:color="@color/button_selectorcolor" />
    </shape></item>

    <!-- By default the background will be this item -->
    <item><shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="3dp" />

        <solid android:color="@color/white_greyish" />
    </shape></item>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/black"/>
    <item android:color="@color/white"></item>
</selector>
```

This is drawable_selector.xml file

Comment: `drawable_selector.xml` doesn't match with `@drawable/loginbutton_selector`

Comment: Oh sorry i didn't see that. But what to do with the error?                   <Button
            android:id="@+id/loginBtn"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:background="@drawable/loginbutton_selector"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="@string/login"
            android:textColor="#009688"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

Comment: Share your error

Comment: Its in the title. couldn't resolve resource @drawable/loginbutton_selector

Answer (score 0):

I made a new XML file name `loginbutton_selector` inside `drawable` folder and it worked.